# Tezos Smart Contract Language Specifications

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, ligo

Is there an equivalent "interface" keyword in any of the Tezos smart contract languages (i.e. smartpy, archetype, ligo) that is similar to solidity's keyword "interface".

If there are any links to github or gitlab that I could study, that would be awesome!!

Comment: https://ligolang.org/ -- great for docs/studying

Answer (score 1):

No

AFAIK none of smart contract languages allow to set type constraints at the contract level.

If you are looking for composability of contracts, you can use modules in Ligo. Here an exemple where the specialized NFT token https://github.com/ligolang/NFT-factory-jsligo/blob/main/contracts/generic_fa2/core/instance/NFT.mligo is composed from a generic FA2 token https://github.com/ligolang/NFT-factory-cameligo/tree/main/contracts/generic_fa2/core/common